# Рассказ о букве Ё (мини-конкурс)

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Почему люди не используют на письме букву "Ё"?**

Как часто задается этот вопрос! Мне кажется, что большинство пользователей думают так: была обычная пара букв Е/Ё, а потом по непонятным причинам решили писать только Е.

Вот, к примеру, ответ на форуме:

"Потому что людям трудно тыкать на эту букву "Ё".Давно уже понятно было.Они лучше будут писать "Е".Ну или просто лень или деградация.Скоро вместо буквы "Щ" начнут писать "Ш",а вместо "Й" будут писать букву "И".И ВСЕМ ХОРОШО".

Рассказывать  о судьбу буквы Ё можно много и долго, вас устанут слушать, а потом всё забудут. И опять будут спрашивать, почему люди не используют на письме букву "Ё"**

А как рассказать историю Ё ** **правильно, но при этом коротко, ясно, живо,  понятно для всех, воздействуя на эмоции и всего в двух-трех небольших предложениях?**

Примите, пожалуйста, участие в мини-конкурсе "правильность, образность, краткость". Тема задана.

Comment: Вера, а зачем в рассказе букве про букву  "е'' воздействовать на эмоции?

Comment: Эмоциональная память  долговременная,  яркий образ лучше запоминается.

Comment: _Vera: Почему **люди** не используют на письме букву "Ё"?_ === Зачем же Вы так о **всех** людях-то?

Comment: Это не я, так звучал вопрос на другом форуме. С другой стороны, вы нарушите Правила орфографии, если будете ее писать во всех словах.

Comment: Зачем вы постоянно пишете словосочетание _правила орфографии_ с прописной буквы? Это ведь неправильно.

Comment: _Vera: "...вы нарушите Правила орфографии, если будете ее писать во всех словах"._ === Vera, рассмешили! Где ж Вы **такие** правила-то нашли? Пишу "ё" во всех словах, где эта буква нужна. Оставляю "е" (там, где нужна "ё")  только в  цитатах (при их копировании). И только от Вас сейчас узнал, что нарушаю этим какие-то мне неведомые правила. ЧуднО!

Comment: Почитайте  Лопатина: § 5. Употребление буквы ё в текстах разного назначения. Да и то разбаловал вас Лопатин,  раньше (в Правилах 1956 года) построже было, только в трех случаях разрешалось писать букву Ё: для предупреждения неверного чтения (узнаем - узнаём), в малоизвестных словах (река Олёкма), в букварях и специальных учебниках.

Comment: Вера, в правилах -56 ни о каких нарушениях орфографии не говорилось. там лишь говорилось об обязательном использовании этой буквы только в том случае, когда может возникнуть неясность, и в некоторых других случаях.

Comment: Tagirix, это не ошибка.  Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Так называется свод правил 1956 года.

Comment: Серж, а в Правилах не говорится об обязательном или факультативном использовании буквы Ё, там говорится просто: "буква Ё ПИШЕТСЯ в следующих случаях". А вообще, надо бы сделать написание Ё ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫМ я не вижу причин не писать её, они кажутся смехотворными.  Тогда,  действительно, давайте и букву Й не обозначать, если неудобно  или не хочется надстрочные знаки ставить. У нас газета "Метро" уже год печатается с буквой Ё, и все замечательно. В глазах от точек не рябит,  частотность слов  Ё невысока (не больше 5%), их даже не замечаешь.

Answer (score 2):

Береги двоеточия смолоду

---

Когда-то наряжал он **ё**лку,

Был не по возрасту смышл**ё**н,

Вес**ё**лый был, носил он ч**ё**лку,

Бывал конфеткой награжд**ё**н.

---

Шли годы, пил он пиво "КОз**е**л",

Ленясь две точки проставлять.

ОсУжд**е**н был, ведь букву прОпил!

З.Ы. Надо на себя пенять.

**P.S.** Я не могу себе представить слово "ёлка" написанным через "е". Взял с полки первую попавшуюся книгу - там всё в порядке (издательство "Музыка", 1979). С каких изданий или "просветительских" рекомендаций начались проблемы, точно 
нельзя сказать; возможно, с появлением компьютерного писательства или вёрстки (на современных клавиатурах буква расположена иначе, чем на пишущих машинках, и загнана в левый верхний угол), или ещё раньше - с распространением дешёвых книжек на газетной бумаге из вторсырья, с газетными же установками при корректуре. В Системе конструкторской документации устранение буквы узаконено ради технического упрощения - вместе с дозволением использовать при отображении десятичных дробей на дисплеях точку вместо запятой (в результате, в переводах стало встречаться бессмысленное выражение "плавающая точка"). Почему подмена этой буквы в литературных текстах вызывает у меня протест - потому что русская письменность предельно фонетична: если что-либо произносится в изменённой относительно написанного форме, то по естественным физиологическим причинам, а не потому, что так предписано учебной фонетической транскрипцией (пусть и полезной для иностранцев или будущих теоретиков) - многие десятилетия без неё успешно обходились.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за участие, всё очень художественно, но вы высказываете версию, что букву  Ё ПЕРЕСТАЛИ писать. А было ли вообще такое золотое время, когда ёлка, весёлый  и др. писались через Ё. Может быть, букву Ё просто и не начинали писать ?

Comment: Коротко не получается - дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

До революции "ё" не писали, так как в спорных случаях можно было поставить "ять" и всем было понятно, что если "ять" то читаем [е], а если "е" - то [йо]. Конфузы конечно случались всё равно. Так Лёв (да-да Л**ё**в) Николаевич Толстой, долго бился с издателями, чтобы персонажа Анны Карениной Лёвина писали через "ё", а не через "е" как какого-то еврея, но тщетно.
В 1918 "ять" отменили, но про "ё" забыли. В результате первый русский чемпион мира по шахматам Александр Алехин вынужден был периодически поправлять тех, кто считал, что его фамилия читается через "ё", хотя это не так. Сталин в ВОВ было заставил всех ставить точки над "ё", но с "оттепелью" ушла и эта обязаность. Сейчас кроме случаев, где возможны ошибки прочтения "ё" факультативна.

Comment: Да, сравним три слова: лес, день, нести. До революции "лес" писался через  "ять", в слове "день" происходило чередование день - дня, там раньше был редуцированный гласный (дьнь). Остается  нести - нёс, где и наблюдалось чередование Е/Ё. Так что пользователь и так мог догадаться, где Е читается как Ё. Поэтому появившаяся в начале 19 века буква Ё так и осталось экспериментальной  в русской графике, к тому же она до 1918 года и в азбуке не числилась. Трудная судьба у буквы, не позавидуешь.

Comment: Марк Из, Вы всегда пишете интересно, не всегда обосновано.

Comment: 1. Выбор между "ять" и "есть" диктовался не прихотью и не необходимостью избежать омонимии (это только в редких случаях), а законами языка и традицией.

Comment: 2. История с Лёвом Толстым напоминает дурной анекдот. Много кто пишет об этом "Лёв", но никто не даёт достаточного подтверждения, что так оно и было.  Ну нет причин там быть Ё.  Лев (имя) изменяется как лев )нарицательное), с беглой гласной. Т.е. там не ять был, а ерь. Ерь в ять регулярно не переходит.

Comment: 3. Лёвин - да. От "Лёва", "Лёвша", некалендарного ЛИ, восходящего к "левый", "левша", но никак не ко льву.

Comment: @behemothus 1. От "ять" "ё" не появлялось, поэтому если не вдаваться в этимологию, правило в целом работало. 2. Послушайте записи голоса самого Л. Н. Толстого, например "Письмо П. Н. Воронову. 24 марта 1908 г." - http://tolstoy.ru/media/audio-recordings/?q=&page=6 3. Про происхождение фамилии "Лёвин" я ничего не писал.

Comment: 1. Именно так. За редчайшими исключениями, вызванными переосмыслением. 2. Но от еря-то не появлялось *никогда*. Ерь доджен был перейти в е, только потом в ё. Таких слов еще меньше, "Лев" к ним не принадлежит. Следовательно, предположение о форме "Лёв" неверно. Я там об этом, ни о чем больше. А то, что граф называет себя "лёвом" - это его право. Может, тоже антисемит ))) Я себя "Дё" иногда называю. От Андрея. ))) 3. Это я написал про происхождение. Потому что там Л**ё**в закономерно.

Comment: @behemothus 2. "Л**ё**в - это старомосковская форма произношения, сокращение "Лёва" используется до сих пор. Стихотворение 1825 г.:
"Наш приятель, Пушкин Лёв,  
‎Не лишён рассудка:  
И с шампанским жирный плов,  
‎И с груздями утка"

Comment: Скращение - не аргумент. Дёма из Дементий, Сёма из Семен.... А насчет старомосковской... Ну может быть, все равно не свидетельствует о её правильности.

Comment: @behemothus, правильно-неправильно, но так было. Стихотворение, приведённое выше, совместно написано Баратынским и Дельвигом, образование которых, было не хуже, чем у Александра Сергеевича, не любившего "ё". Именно поэтому я и написал, что путаница е-ё стала возникать ещё до революции, хотя согласен, что тогда её было значительно меньше.

Comment: Давайте откатим. Вы привели этого "Лёва" как аргумент в пользу того, что "Лев" (имя) возникло по недоразумению из-за неупотребления Ё? Если нет, то разговор яйца выеденного не стоит, не в тему. А если все-таки именно с этой целью, как аргумент, то он вполне нашел свое опровержение в дальгейшем разговоре.

Comment: @behemothus В XIX веке параллельно были имена "Лев" и Лёв", однако из-за отсутствия ёфикации об этом сейчас мало кто знает.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27206/discussion-between---and-behemothus).

Answer (score 1):

Я использую. Особенно она нужна в тех случаях, когда возможно двоякое понимание.

Comment: Это правильно при наличии вариантов при прочтении (например, все и всё),  и это  соответствует Правилам орфографии. Но почему в других случаях  (при отсутствии вариантов) правила рекомендуют не писать букву Ё? Если вы знаете причину, то расскажите нам об этом (составьте маленький рассказик в художественном или публицистическом стиле).

Comment: Какие правила? В других случаях буква ***ё*** факультативна.

Comment: И ещё: не используют в печатных текстах, в интернете. А так,кто не использует - все используют почти.

Comment: «Не используют в печатных текстах, в интернете»

Что за бред, извините?

Comment: Это не бред! В печатных текстах, в интернете многие не используют эту букву. Не на всех клавиатурах она есть. Да и к тому же экономия времени, чтобы не искать эту букву. За исключением таких слов, как все- всё и и т.д.

Comment: Впервые слышу об этом. Все СМИ, которые я читаю, используют Ё спокойно. Не знаю, откуда вы берете такую информацию.

Comment: Прочитайте ссылку, которую я привел в ответе.

Comment: Я не дочитал: слишком много букв, как говорится. Можете вкратце сказать?

Comment: Tangrix, Серж, как обычно, выразился очень категорично и не приведши доводов. Но по сути он прав. Использования е и ё по современным правилам регулируется правилом: ***Е вместо Ё везде, кроме трех случаев: 1. Для исключения графической омонимии (омографии), возникающей при написании через ё (все и всё, ведро и вёдро и т.п.) - и то только в тех случаях, когда может возникнуть двусмысленность, 2. В иноязычных и редко употребляемых именах собственных (чаще всего - топонимах) 3. В изданиях детских и учебных для иностранцев. В остальных случаях Ё использовать нельзя***

Comment: Иногда издательства или редакция (не все!) предоставляют автору право использовать ё последовательно во всем тексте. Но тогда уж - именно ***во всем тексте***, как в упомянутых учебных изданиях. Т.е. "факультативность" и тут нельзя понимать как отсутствие нормы.

Comment: Вот АБСОЛЮТНО ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ПОДХОД: Ё пишется или во всем тексте, или выборочно по особым правилам.

Answer (score 1):

Мой ответ всем Ёфикаторам.

***Исчез властитель осужденный,

Могучий баловень побед,

И для изгнанника вселенной

Уже потомство настает.***
("Наполеон")

Пушкин прекрасно обходился без ё, которой не было в алфавите.
Когда было очень надо, писали IO. 
Потом (в конце XVIII века) придумали вот это Ё на всякий случай, когда есть сомнения или двусмысленность; как и кто - это отдельная история для тех, кому написание "по Пушкину" кажется неправильным. Ну а потом, когда надо было учить малограмотных, Пушкина не читающих и языка не чувствующих, пошла волна повальной ёфикации.

(Чем могу. Короче не получится, 2-3 предложения - это Вы загнули. А на эмоции воздействовать не хочу, только на разум)

Comment: _behemothus: "…для тех, кому написание "по Пушкину" кажется неправильным"._ === Да у Пушкина-то в приведённом Вами стихотворении написано правильно. Написано так, как и произносилось в его время: _осуждЕнный, настаЕт_. Потому ему Ё в этих строках и не понадобилось. === А вот почему в нынешних (не пушкинских!) текстах _антиёфикаторы_ пишут _осужденный_ "по Пушкину",  я не знаю. Писали бы **осуждЁнный**, меньше бы было говорящих **осУжденный**.

Comment: behemothus, у Вас история буквы Ё как-то сомнительно излагается, у меня другая версия: Буква Ё  была создана для обозначения МЯГКОГО ВАРИАНТА УДАРНОГО ЗВУКА О, который  появился  в результате окончательного закрепления в языке особого фонетического чередования гласных звуков, например: село – сёла, ледяной – лёд (раньше говорили ледяной – лед).  Возникнув В РАЗГОВОРНОЙ РЕЧИ, новое произношение во второй половине XVIII века стало активно проникать в литературный язык.

Comment: В жанрах высокого стиля, например в трагедии,  оно  долгое время считалось НЕДОПУСТИМЫМ, дольше других чтение Е сохраняется и в философской лирике.  Но постепенно вариативность исчезает,  мягкий ударный звук О  окончательно ЗАКРЕПЛЯЕТСЯ в языке.

Comment: Таким образом,  звук, обозначаемый буквой Ё, в конце концов УТВЕРДИЛСЯ В ЯЗЫКЕ, что нельзя сказать о букве Ё.  С одной стороны,  «неблагородное» происхождение буквы не способствовало ее распространению. Кроме того, чередование Е/Ё можно было просто не отражать на письме, да и для набора буквы  Ё требовались дополнительные материальные затраты. Таким образом, в текстах конца  19 века буква Ё,  как правило, ЧИТАЕТСЯ, НО НЕ ПИШЕТСЯ

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем участникам конкурса, я думаю, что обсуждение этой темы оказалось полезным. Главное, стало понятно, что буква Ё особенная и для нее существуют особые правила: или мы пишем Ё во всех словах данного текста, или пишем ее по особым правилам.

И вот мой ответ:

**Эпиграф:** «В какое короткое время безобразный звук сей ко вреду словесности распространился: сперва существовал он в одном произношении, и то в самых простонародных словах; потом выдумали для него новую букву, и начали оный употреблять в письме, сперва в комедиях и баснях, а теперь уже он поселился в поэмы и трагедии. Не справедлива ли русская пословица: посади невежу за стол, он и ноги на стол?»  **(А.С. Шишков).**

У буквы  Ё особая история и особое положение в языке. Звук, ею обозначаемый, относился к просторечию,  и до самой середины 19 века разговорное "ёканье" никак на приветствовалось ревнителями  чистоты русской речи.  Тем не менее  мягкий ударный звук О все-таки закрепился в языке, а вот "изобретенную" Карамзиным  букву Ё обозначать не спешили.

**Да что это за буква – так, фонетический значок для особого прочтения Е.  Несамостоятельная эта буква, на которую никогда не падает ударение, и так можно догадаться, где Е и где Ё. Даже реформа 1918 года ничего не изменила,  даже сталинский указ не помог.**

Но трудно стать настоящей буквой, когда тебя считают только фонетическим знаком.  Буква Ё  как молоденькое деревцо, задавленное гранитными плитами, нет деревцу роста. Поэтому  давайте обозначать букву Ё.

Интересная информация о букве Ё
http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-11177/

Comment: _Vera: "Поэтому давайте обозначать букву Ё"._ === Давайте! _"Хочешь изменить мир – начни с себя!"_ ("изобретЁнную").

Comment: Тогда, наверное, все на форуме должны обозначать Ё. Кстати,  вот в трудах  историков  в 19 веке Ё не обозначена: "Когда же мы отступили от Бога, прияли новую, изобретенную умом человеческим в угодность страстям..."[Н. М. Карамзин. Том 9 (1816-1820)] "Людвиг велел судить его светским судом и запер в железную клетку, изобретенную самим кардиналом,  [Т. Н. Грановский. (1816-1820)]

Comment: _Vera: "Тогда, наверное, все на форуме должны обозначать Ё". _ === Ну, ждите, ждите…

Comment: _Vera: "Кстати, вот в трудах историков в 19 веке Ё не обозначена… **изобретенную**… [Н. М. Карамзин. Том 9 (1816-1820)]… [Т. Н. Грановский. (1816-1820)]"._ === Ну и?.. Никто, по-моему, и не утверждал, что когда-либо Ё печаталось ВО ВСЕХ произведениях и у ВСЕХ авторов. У Пушкина -- встречалось.  Что же до Ё в слове "изобретЁнный", то у Карамзина и Грановского этой буквы могло там и не быть по причине, совсем не связанной с печатью: скорее всего, это слово оба этих писателя произносили с  Е, а не "по народному выговору" (победившему впоследствии) -- с Ё.

Comment: Да и ударение в этом слове, по-моему, в первой половине 19-го века было на третьем слоге: **изобрЕтенный**.  Так что на Карамзина и иже с ним при сегодняшнем написании не стоит ориентироваться. Пишите смело Ё!

Answer (score 0):

По поводу прозвучавших в этой теме некоторых утверждений.

===

> **До революции "ё" не писали...**

===

> **Пушкин прекрасно обходился без ё...**

===

Писали и до революции. Было и у Пушкина.

Из "Евгения Онегина", изданного в **1825** году:

===

*"Я был **далёко**..."*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===

*"Уж барабаном **пробуждён**"*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===

> **в спорных случаях можно было поставить "ять" и всем было понятно,
>   что  если "ять", то читаем [е]**

По-моему, не все слова с "ять" всегда читались с [е]. Из Грота:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]