# Как правильно читать эту строку из "Евгения Онегина"?

Tags: орфоэпия, поэзия, е-или-ё

Каждый раз, читая эту строку из "Онегина", не знаю, куда ставить ударение так, чтобы сохранить рифму и не исковеркать слова. Из [главы первой](http://www.as-pushkin.ru/index.php?cnt=8&sub=1&page=3), строфы XVI:

> Уж тёмно: в санки он садится.
>   «Пади, пади!» — раздался крик;
>   Морозной пылью серебрится
>   Его бобровый воротник.
>   К Talon помчался: он уверен,
>   Что там уж ждет его Каверин.
>   Вошел: и пробка в потолок,
>   Вина кометы брызнул ток,
>   **Пред ним roast-beef окровавленный,**
>   И трюфли, роскошь юных лет,
>   Французской кухни лучший цвет,
>   И Стразбурга пирог нетленный
>   Меж сыром лимбургским живым
>   И ананасом золотым.

Чтобы сохранить рифму, мне приходится ставить ударение на Е в "окровавленный", так что получается Ё. С таким ударением слово звучит довольно непривычно, да и рифма не сочетается с "нетленный".

Есть ли другой способ читать эту строфу?

Comment: Если вы получили полезный ответ, отметьте его галочкой, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Именно так и читать: с ударением на -влЕнн-, но без перехода звука в Ё. 
Это не поэтическая вольность, наоборот, жесткое орфоэпическое требование того времени.
Во времена Пушкина Ё еще не получила такого широкого распространения. В народной, разговорной речи звук, обозначаемый через Ё, использовался довольно широко, но никак не в высоком стиле (кроме некоторых слов с корневым Ё - типа слёзы и звёзды, где такой переход Ё<Е произошел несколько раньше - причем вопреки общей тенденции).

А уж в поэтической речи в подобных словах (в суффиксах особенно!) просто невозможно было использовать Ё. Я думаю, до начала Серебряного века вы вообще не найдёте примеров бесспорного Ё. Разве что у Некрасова - как стилизация народной речи...

Факт довольно известный, мне невмоготу искать авторитетные ссылки, просто пример из того же Пушкина, которым эту мысль обычно и иллюстрируют.

*Исчез властитель осужденный,

Могучий баловень побед,

И для изгнанника вселенной

Уже потомство настает.*
(Наполеон)

Сразу два Е на месте современного Ё. Иных примеров вы не найдете.

Подробнее - тут: [Рассказ о букве Ё (мини-конкурс)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417567)

Comment: Вот интересно ещё, что в первой строчке "уж т**ё**мно". ;) Сейчас так почти не говорят.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - что в первой строчке "уж тёмно" - а вот я не очень уверен, что Пушкин имел в виду именно Ё. Скорее всего надо произносить "т**е**мно" - с ударением на первый слог, но это настолько непривычно современному читателю, что произойдет сбой ритма. Посему редакторы скорее всего пошли по пути выбора меньшего из зол, заменив произношение на современное, но сохранив ритм. Впрочем, не берусь утверждать наверняка.

Comment: Хм, и правда интересно. А хорошо бы было, если б можно было узнать!)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой впрочем, там же ЕРЬ исторический тЁмный <> тЬма, а вот он-то (в отличие от ятя) мог перейти в Ё довольно рано и попасть в высокий стиль к пушкинским временам. Так что - Бог знает.

Answer (score 3):

При чтении стихотворений, следуя его ритму, иногда приходится произносить слова с непривычным ударением, поскольку авторы прибегают к такому приёму,  чтобы сохранить этот самый ритм. В данном случае ситуация другая (см. ответ Behemothus), рифма идеальная. Заменять букву **е** на **ё** не нужно. *Окров**á**вленный* — *окровавл**é**нный*.

[ОКРОВÁВЛЕННЫЙ](https://books.google.ru/books?id=datnAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=QqFok3_atl&sig=ACfU3U2e3ILm3qKOlc52yZmCFm9TGlUouA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi45Y_4vtvoAhVGfZoKHZB1DnkQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false), допустимо (в поэтической речи) *окровавлённый* и **устарелое** *окровавлéнный*. Например: «Пред ним roast-beef окровавлéнный...».

Comment: А не лишнее ли замечание про изменение места ударения, если старая форма все-таки окровавлéнный?

Comment: @Aer  Спасибо за замечание. Исправил ответ, так пойдёт?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Признаюсь, самому мне и в голову не пришло не заменять Е на Ё.

Comment: @Gallifreyan  И вам спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: Спасибо, что заметили! Я имел в виду, что, может быть, такое произношение было естественно Пушкину, то есть он не прибегал ни к каким специальным приемам.